# Is it possible to return a variable number of colums in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select

I've the following situation:

Using sqlite, I've two tables I make a natural join with, which leaves a result like this one:

```
Fields from table1... Matching data from table2

Id1      Id2...             Atr1      Value1
Id1      Id2...             Atr2      Value2
Id1      Id2...             Atr3      Value3
OtherId1 OtherId2...        OtherAtr1 OtherValue1
OtherId1 OtherId2...        OtherAtr2 OtherValue2
```

It would be more comfortable if I could return as result of a query something like:

```
Id1      Id2...         Atr1      Value1      Atr2      Value2       Atr3   Value3

OtherId1 OtherId2...    OtherAtr1 OtherValue1 OtherAtr2 OtherValue2
```

Or, at least:

```
Id1      Id2...         Atr1      Value1      Atr2      Value2       Atr3   Value3

OtherId1 OtherId2...    OtherAtr1 OtherValue1 OtherAtr2 OtherValue2  NULL   NULL
```

I believe this breaks too much the relational model and cannot be achieved in any way, but maybe I'm missing something, after all there are some database systems that offer SQL functions that break it, although I think that way less that what I'm trying to.

Comment: SQLite does not support dynamic sql. This can be done by specifying and hardcoding the column names. Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: I don't know SqlLite but this looks more like pivoting, if you always have 3 attributes then you should be able to do this without needing any dynamic sql.